# can't fetch messages with its commets in chart system

Tags: php, mysql

The following code is fetching messages (status) with its comments from MySQL database from tables CHART and COMMENTS. The problem with the code is dieing when it's returning the messages from database causing the comment field and messages not appear in an HTML page because the msg_id didn't match anything in the table COMMETS.

Can someone help me to solve this? or what is the better way i can do this?

**sample code
Note: First i have a form am using to create messages then the bellow code to fetch my messages to be commented and return the comments bellow the message which has been commented.**

```
<?php
//MYQSL query to select from two tables chart and comments
//this query is not returning anything because the script is dieing ON ch.msg_id=co.comment_id, it cant find co.comment_id because has not yet created.
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ch.msg , ch.msg_id , co.comment , co.comment_id
                                 FROM chart AS ch
                                 JOIN comments AS co
                                 ON ch.msg_id=co.comment_id
                                 ORDER BY ch.msg_id, co.comment_id");
$last_msg = null;
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
   if ($row['msg_id'] !== $last_msg) {
     if ($last_msg !== null) {
       echo "<table>";
     }
     echo "<table border='1' width='600px'>
           <tr>
           <td>
           $row[msg]
           </td>
           </tr>\n";
     $last_msg = $row['msg_id'];
   }

  //all comments should appear here if comment_id match msg_id in COMMENTS table
   echo("
   <tr>
   <td>

   $row[comment]
   <p></p>

   //HTML form which will insert the comments into table COMMENTS
   //this form should appear below each message since its a comment field
   <form action='drop_comment.php' method='post'>
   <input type='text' name='comment' placeholder='drop a comment...' value='' class='add_hook'>
   <input name='comment_id' type='hidden'  value='$row[msg_id]'>
   </form>
   </td>
   </tr>
   ");
   echo "</table>";
   }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would the Comment ID be the Message ID?

I might be wrong but shouldn't the comment record have a column such as CommentMessageID?

Comment: i was trying to mean that if the msg_id is 2121 the comment hidden field will echo that id and place it in table comments at comment_id row then the MySQL query has to match the msg_id with comment_id to display the comments bellow the message which has that id, if that was wrong kindly correct me

Comment: Your code says

    //this query is not returning anything because the script is dieing ON ch.msg_id=co.comment_id, it cant find co.comment_id because has not yet created.

What is the structure of your comments and messages table?

Comment: comments table contains id, msg_id and msg while the chart table has id, comment_id and comment thats all